# Javascript works on jsfiddle but not my site

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on jsfiddle, and got my code working. But when I copy-pasted it, it stopped working. For some reason, it doesn't go through the first function when clicked, but works fine on jsfiddle.

Here's the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/katcheng/jTwY5/10/

and here's my site: http://sulley.cah.ucf.edu/~ka324464/dig3716c/labs/lab12_javascript_events/lab12.html

```
function zoomIn(event){
alert('omg seriously.');
event.preventDefault();
var fullDiv = document.getElementById('fullsize');

while (fullDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
    fullDiv.removeChild(fullDiv.lastChild);
}

var newIMG = document.createElement('img');
newIMG.setAttribute('src', images[0]);

fullDiv.appendChild(newIMG);

var newPElement = document.createElement('p');
var newCAPtxt = document.createTextNode(captions[0]);

newPElement.appendChild(newCAPtxt);
fullDiv.appendChild(newPElement);
}
```

^That's the function it isn't running through. Help?

Comment: The console is your friend... `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null ` -- put your script after your content.

Answer (score 2):

Call your `javascript` file `gallery.js` after the content is loaded.

Like this,

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<!-- Your content here-->

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/gallery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```